# Why is my mat-header-cell not rendering the class .mat-header-cell after updating from Angular Material 14 to 15?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I've updated Angular Material from 14 to 15 and now the mat-header-cell teh TH inside my angular material table is not rendering the class .mat-header-cell in my scss.

my HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="created">
      <th id="th_created" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        Created
      </th>
      <td
        mat-cell
        *matCellDef="let element"
        [class.error-state]="element.status === 'ERROR'"
      >
        {{ element.created | date: "dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss" }}
      </td>
</ng-container>
```

my SCSS:

```
.mat-header-cell {
  padding: 0 0 0 4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: $primary !important;
  color: white;
  border: solid 0.5px white;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  &:hover {
    background-color: $secondary !important;
  }
}
```

Now to make it work again, I need to add the mat-header-cell inside a tag class like this class="mat-header-cell". I want to make it work again without any changes.

In the Documentation it says, that there is no need to add the ::ng-deep is just how it is in my code. Also try without a Point in my scss just like mat-header-cell{} and also th.mat-header-cell{}